# Selenium WebDriver Python 3 Refresh Page Until Text Found And Afterwards Click To Buy

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, refresh

I am a total noob that tries to get together a code that will do below things.

**1.) Log in with my credentials to the page https://www.alza.sk/EN/**

**2.) Refreshes the page in a specific interval, for example "60 seconds"**

**3.) Checks for the “In stock” text on any product displayed or a specific one product that will be opened in the one browser tab"**

**4.) Click on the “Add to cart” button beside the specific product that will be opened in the mentioned one browset tab and continue to the shopping cart by clickiny on “Proceed to Checkout” button, afterwards click on “Continue” button, if popup window displays with two buttons “Do not add anything” and “Add the selected items to your cart“ then click on the first button “Do not add anything”. In the next page choose the “Bratislava - main shop” checkbox and after that choose “Confirm your selection” button in the popup window. Afterwards click on “All payments option” section so all options are displayed and choose the “Cash / Card (when collected) checkbox. After that click on “Continue” button. And this is the step when i need to login by entering my credentials. So this i”ll update later today. But i suppose it would be best to log in in the Step 1.) as i described.**

This is all i could so far get together, but i am unable to add all i described, so it will work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.alza.sk/EN/")
while(True):
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep("60")
```

Comment: OK. And what exactly is the problem? You did not show the url, not specified the element you want to click there. Without details the solution will be general, exactly as what you wrote in the question.

Comment: The problem is that the script i “wrote” only refreshes the page and that’s it. I need also the second and third steps. URL is this one for example “https://m.alza.sk/prislusenstvo-k-smart-hodinkam/18855196.htm” i need to check if the text “Na sklade” is present on the page and if so, i need the script to click on “Kupit” button and continue to the shopping cart and through the whole process. The one main issue i did not mention is that i also probably need to log in with my credentials first, or somewhere in the process, because without it i wont be able to finish the checkout.

Comment: Do you want the page to refresh until the element you are looking for is visible?

Comment: I updated the main post with everything i  want to do. But yes, u are correct, this is the section 3.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("input url here")
expected_text="Available"
actual_text=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Available"]').text
while actual_text!=True:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(input time interval here)
    if expected_text==actual_text:
         actual_text=True
         driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Available"]').click()
#add other steps
```

This is just a suggestion on how to proceed with the script. If you can update the question with the URL and proper code, it will be easier to give a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion. I at least updated the description, so it's maybe clearer what i want to do. The page and texts i provided are in my native language, but ill update them to english version so its easier to understand what i am looking for and what i want to do. Regarding the “proper code” this is all i got, i was unable to figure out the rest, thats why i am here in the first place.

Comment: I updated the original post by adding additional details. The login process i did not described yet, but i suppose it would be best to log in in the beggining in the 1.) Step

Comment: are you going to be able to write the code further according to my updated steps I provided in the original post?

Comment: I did not understand the question here. Is there any error or any step you are stuck at? Or do you want me to develop a script for your website?

Comment: well, i said that i am a total noob, so if u would be able to develop it, that would be awesome, if not, then i'll have to somehow learn it myself and use at least the part u provided.

Comment: SO is a place to discuss issues and suggest solutions and share ideas. Give it a try and if you face any hiccups while learning & developing, you are always welcome. All the best :)